# Is there a official plugin for materialize

Tags: yii2

I was searching for documentation for materialize and Yii2 but I can't find information about it.

I want to know if I can use materialize using Yii2 or whether or not there is an oficial plugin for this?

Comment: are you talking about materialize front end framework? http://materializecss.com

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about  materializecss.com front working with Yii2 framework instead of bootstrap.

Comment: Okay, just confirming. That shouldn't be a problem at all. You can include materialize a few different ways. Check out their getting started documentation: http://materializecss.com/getting-started.html -- for quick and easy tests you can just reference the cdn

Comment: Thanks Jase. Actually I have a project that is using materialize but it does not work fine, some css styles cause problems.

Comment: If you install it with bootstrap, they do clash with one another, but In my experience it runs fine all on its own.